# Is it possible to execute with different URL from endpoint of custom activity?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, custom-activity

Is it possible to call execute URL from different endpoints?

For example,
I set the installed app and set custom activity with the endpoint as https://some-endpoint.com/ for the message.

For your information, the URL below is not an actual URL, it is only an example.

What I want is to save, publish, validate with https://some-endpoint.com/ this URL, BUT RUN EXECUTE METHOD WITH DIFFERENT URL.

Therefore, I set config.json like this:

BEFORE:

"arguments": {
        "execute": {
            "inArguments": [
                {
                    "contactKey": "{{Contact.Key}}"
                    },
                {
                    "Name": "{{Contact.Attribute.KIB3.Name}}"
                    }
                ],
            "outArguments": [
            ],
            "url": "https://some-endpoint.com/jourenybuilder/execute",
            "verb": "POST",
            "body": "",
            "header": "",
            "format": "json",
            "useJwt": false,
            "timeout": 10000
        }
    },

NOW:
"arguments": {
        "execute": {
            "inArguments": [
                {
                    "contactKey": "{{Contact.Key}}"
                    },
                {
                    "Name": "{{Contact.Attribute.KIB3.Name}}"
                    }
                ],
            "outArguments": [
            ],
            "url": "https://another-endpoint.com/v1/S/mktcloud/messages",
            "verb": "POST",
            "body": "",
            "header": "",
            "format": "json",
            "useJwt": false,
            "timeout": 10000
        }
    },

However, in heroku application (which is based on node.js), it executes the same way even though I changed the application in NOW status.

So I want to check 2 things regarding this,

1) Is it possible to execute a URL that is different from the endpoint?  
2) If it is possible, should I have to do additional changes? 
(Currently, I 've changed only config.json)

I hope I could find my answer soon........
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, your endpoints can be whatever you specify them in the config.json - they can be, and often are, different. Any change you make to the config.json, or configuration part of a custom activity, does ***require*** you to update and re-configure within the journey itself for it to take in the change to configuration.

Changes purely in the execute logic itself does ***not*** require an update to the journey.